# Arraylist toString() method and duplicate values

Tags: java, arraylist, contains

Below I have posted a snippet of code I have written whilst trying to replicate the game minesweeper in very simplistic terms. I've got a slight query...

The code below generates a pair of co-ordinates, checks to see if the particular co-ordinates are already held in the `ArrayList`, and if not, adds them to the list, repeating this process until I have a list of ten mine locations. on running the program I have found that the list contains duplicates when it shouldn't...

```
public class MineSweeper {
    private static ArrayList mines;

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MineSweeper ms = new MineSweeper();

    }

    public MineSweeper(){
        mines = new ArrayList(10);
        generateMines();
        showMines();

    }

    private void generateMines(){
        int x = 0, y = 0, mineCount = 0;
        Random rnd = new Random();  
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();

        while(mineCount != 10)
        {
            x = rnd.nextInt(9) + 1;
            y = rnd.nextInt(9) + 1;
            str.append(x).append(",").append(y);   
            if(!(mines.contains(str.toString())))
            {
                mines.add(str);
                mineCount ++;
            }
            str = new StringBuilder();
        }
    }

    private void showMines(){
        System.out.println(mines.toString());
    }
}
```

I believed that my `if statement` would catch any duplicates but was wrong.
I eventually solved the problem by changing the `if statement` to `if(!(mines.toString().contains(str)))`

Can somebody enlighten me on the difference please?

Comment: What version or Java are you using? How did it let you create a `new ArrayList(10)`?

Comment: @JohnBupit just checked, jdk1.8.0_45, never gave any warnings???

Comment: What if you create you ArrayList like this:
`private static ArrayList<String> mines` and then in constructor you say `mines = new ArrayList<>()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are checking if `mines` contains `str.toString()`, but adding `str`, which is a `StringBuilder` instance. Since all the objects you're adding are `StringBuilder`s, `mines` can't contain a `String`.

You should choose which class you're going with, and stick to it. E.g., with `String`s:

```
if (!(mines.contains(str.toString()))) {
    mines.add(str.toString());
    mineCount++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It could be an issue with the "if(!(mines.contains(str.toString())))", i just dont know how the coordinates are saved and accessed by the "ArrayList" object.

Answer (score 0):

ArrayList contains StringBuilder's and in `mines.contains(str.toString())` you compare to a String (str.toString) so you compare a StringBuilder with a String thus they are never equal.

You have quite a number of other problems as well, for example mines field is static, Random is not, etc

Answer (score 0):

if we look at your if statement:

```
mines.contains(str.toString())
```

`mines` is an `ArrayList` of generic type `StringBuilder` (because it had undefined generic type it automatically uses `ArrayList<Object>` ). This can be checked if you do this

```
System.out.println(mines.get(1) instanceof StringBuilder); //print true
```

`str` is a `StringBuilder` object which you have cast to a `String`. You are thus comparing a `StringBuilder` object to a `String` object. It is important to note that `contains()` uses `equals()` for comparison.

this can be illustrated with this example:

```
StringBuilder testStrB = new StringBuilder("test");
System.out.println(testStrB.equals(testStrB.toString())); //print false
```

in fact, I get the warning that `equals()` is used on incompatible types.

with your working statement

```
mines.toString().contains(str)
```

it seems that `contains()` accepts a `CharSequence`, which is a super-interface of `StringBuilder`. As `mines.toString` uses `contains()` of the entire `String` searching for a `CharSequence` represented by `StringBuilder`, it works.

**in summary:**

your initial (non-working) if statement tried to use (for each element of `mines`)

```
StringBuilder.equals(String)
```

whereas your working if statement used

```
String.contains(StringBuilder)
```

which allows `StringBuilder` to be used as a `CharSequence` and thus compared.

for interest:

```
System.out.println(testStrB.toString().equals(testStrB)); //prints false
// (and incompatible types warning)
```

so a `String` cannot EQUAL a `StringBuilder`, but can CONTAIN it. Probably because `equals()` takes an `Object` and `contains()` takes a `CharSequence`